# Adding tftp sections using virsh net-update

Tags: tftp, virsh

Is it possible to add a `tftp` section into the virtual network configuration using `virsh net-update`?

---

For example, it is possible to add a host IP (Reserve an IP for a specific guest) using:

```
virsh net-update mynet add ip-dhcp-host \
  "<host mac='52:54:01:02:03:04' name='machine' ip='192.168.123.10'/>" \
  --live --config
```

However, trying net-update with `tftp` as following

```
virsh net-update mynet add tftp \
  "<tftp  root='tftpboot'/>" \
  --live --config
```

would fail as the tftp section is not found. (even trying `ip-tftp` would fail)

---

Further info: virsh documentation specifies the available sections as following

> section is one of ""bridge", "domain", "ip", "ip-dhcp-host", "ip-dhcp-range", "forward", "forward-interface", "forward-pf", "portgroup", "dns-host", "dns-txt", or "dns-srv", each section being named by a concatenation of the xml element hierarchy leading to the element being changed. For example, "ip-dhcp-host" will change a  element that is contained inside a  element inside an  element of the network.

Does that mean that tftp is not supported for usage with `net-update`?